# How to change the UI contrast without changing the UI theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use VSCODE for java development.

I use Light theme, and find the degre to which the colours are dimmed personally troublesome. Maybe it is related to my eyesight.

How can I use better contrast code colours without changing UI theme?

I can't use dark themes - them are too hard to use with bad eyesight.
I don't like high contrast themes - I personally don't like the visual choices made in high-contrast mode (UI element edges, widget borders).
I need *normal* contrasted colours.

(I think IDEA's colours/contrast is Ok)

Comment: VS Code's colors are quite configurable using [`workbench.colorCustomizations`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme).  It sounds like you want something very custom, so you'll probably have to take the time to set your own colors.

Comment: You could probably find a theme based on IDEA

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments, you can customize colouring using the [`workbench.colorCustomizations`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme) setting. But for you, I'm assuming you will want to / have to change a lot of things, so that might be an unwieldly / bulky solution.

I'd honestly recommend just searching the VS Code extension marketplace for a colour theme that suits your needs. If you don't find one, you can create your own (see [the related docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_creating-your-own-color-theme)).

---

That being said, to answer the question you have posed, I'm not sure if that's possible even by writing an extension. See https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview, which states:

> However, we also impose [restrictions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/overview#restrictions) upon extensions to ensure the stability and performance of VS Code. For example, extensions cannot access the DOM of VS Code UI.

So if you really want to do this, you'll have to hack it by going into the installed source files of VS Code on your machine and editing it to add something like the following to one of the CSS files:

```css
/* use this if you only want to change editor panels */
.editor-instance { filter: contrast(1.5); }

/* use this to change the entire UI */
.monaco-workbench { filter: contrast(1.5); }
```

You might also want to tinker with [other filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) like `brightness`.

You'd probably have to do this again every time VS Code updates. Not very convenient, right? That's why I'd suggest the other listed approaches.